# php form POST- variable can't increment

Tags: php

I'd like to increment a variable on clicking a submit button with name="ticker".

```
$speed = 0;

if ( isset($_POST['ticker'])){
    echo $speed++; 
}
```

What I want is to be able to repeatedly click the button and see 1 added to total each time clicked. It seems to work once and then stays at "1". Why?

Comment: Because you're setting it to 0 every time.

Answer (score 4):

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['speed'])) $_SESSION['speed'] = 0;

if(isset($_POST['ticker'])){ /* If there is already a value set */
  $_SESSION['speed']++; /* Increment by 1 */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to increment variable after clicking submit, you should store this value to `$_SESSION['speed']` and after that increment it. In this case you set speed on value 0 and each time you click on the submit is incremented by one.